# Assigning variable for dynamic filename in Python

Tags: python, wlst

I am new to python scripting and am required to build a script for WebLogic Server. The requirement is to use a file (type .rpd) from assigned location for deployment. The file type would remain same throughout, however, the file name would change.

Given this condition, I tried the below methods on assigning file to the variable. Both the below methods are not working.

```
rpdfile = "*.rpd"
rpdlocation = "/u02/RPD_Upload/"+rpdfile+
```

or

```
rpdlocation = "/u02/RPD_Upload/*.rpd
```

I get invalid syntax error while running the python. Experts please help me understand on assigning such variables.

Comment: Simple syntax errors: in the first snippet it's the last `+` that causes problems, in the second one you have to close quotes. Also, if you're about to use python, consider at least skimming through the [tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/).

Comment: Thanks Georg for pointing out the mistake and also the tutorial introduction. But am still seeing the error in the stdout as below :`javax.management.RuntimeMBeanException: javax.management.RuntimeMBeanException: Repository File '/u02/RPD_Upload/*.rpd' does not exist or is not accessible.`    Guess the WLST interpreter is seeing the file as *.rpd itself , rather than (any filename).rpd.

Comment: It sounds to me like you need the [glob module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/glob.html) to find all filenames that match the mask and pass them one by one to your service.

Comment: Thanks a ton, Georg !!\n Using glob , I was able to get the variable with desired value.

Answer (score 0):

For your first method, you are not appending correctly. You have an extra '+' at the end of the line. It should look like this:

```
rpdfile = "*.rpd"
rpdlocation = "/u02/RPD_Upload/" + rpdfile
```

For your second method, you are not closing the double-quote. See below:

```
rpdlocation = "/u02/RPD_Upload/*.rpd"
```

Comment: Thanks Mantazer for your inputs, I have crossed this part but am still seeing the error in the stdout as below :`javax.management.RuntimeMBeanException: javax.management.RuntimeMBeanException: Repository File '/u02/RPD_Upload/*.rpd' does not exist or is not accessible.`    Guess the WLST interpreter is seeing the file as *.rpd itself , rather than (any filename).rpd.